# Motorola g2 flashing issues

Tags: motorola-moto-g2

I have installed cm 13 on my moto g2 xt1068.I have twrp installed.I want to install gapps but flashing that it gives me binary file issues.is arm or x86 suitable for moto g2 xt1068? Which 1 is okay ?reply fast.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all phones are ARM.  The Moto G2 is no exception.